# Binding ViewModel Property in a DataGrid, The Datagrid is inside a UserControl, Which is inside another usercontrol

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, datagrid

I have a Datagrid which is present inside user control, which is inside another user control. The View has only one view model and there is no separate ViewModel for any of the usercontrols. ViewModel is wired using prism: `ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"`

The issue I'm facing is I want to bind a VM property to data grid column which is having a button. I want to set the IsEnabled Property of the button based on the ViewModel property.

This is what I have used inside the Button style.
DataTrigger I have written this:

```
Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorLevel=3, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}, Path=IsEncounterLocked}" Value="True"
```

This is what I have used inside the Button style.
DataTrigger I have written this:

```
Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorLevel=3, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}, Path=IsEncounterLocked}" Value="True"
```

Whole element:

```
            <DataTemplate x:Key="HoverDeleteColumnTemplate">
                <Button AutomationProperties.Name="HistorySummary.DiagnosticHistoryDeleteButton" 
                        Content="{StaticResource actionIconDelete}"
                        Click="DeleteButton_Click"
                        Command="{Binding ElementName=DiagnosticHistoryUserControl, Path=DiagnosticHistoryDeleteCommand}" 
                        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=DiagnosticHistoryUserControl, Path=DiagnosticHistoryDeleteCommandParameter}">
                    <Button.Style>
                        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource HiddenActionButtonIcon}" TargetType="Button">
                            <Setter Property="Button.Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Button.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Style>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>
            <Style x:Key="HoverColumnStyle">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="DataGridRow.Background" Value="{StaticResource Glacier}"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
            <DataTemplate x:Key="HoverAddHpiColumnTemplate">
                <Button Content="Add to HPI"
                        Width="86"
                        Command="{Binding ElementName=DiagnosticHistoryUserControl, Path=DiagnosticHistoryAddToHpiCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=DiagnosticHistoryUserControl, Path=DiagnosticHistoryAddToHpiCommandParameter}">
                    <Button.Style>
                        <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource HiddenActionButton}" TargetType="Button">
                            <Setter Property="Button.Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                            <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="True"/>
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridRow}}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True">
                                    <Setter Property="Button.Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                </DataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger>
                                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,AncestorLevel=3, AncestorType={x:Type Grid}}, Path=IsEncounterLocked}" Value="True"/>
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Obsvalue}" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Obsinterpretation}" Value="{x:Null}"/>
                                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
                                    <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="Add to HPI button is only enabled if the selected study has either an Interpretation or Result documented."/>
                                    <Setter Property="ToolTipService.ShowOnDisabled" Value="True"/>
                                </MultiDataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </Button.Style>
                </Button>
            </DataTemplate>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid Background="White">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Row="0"
                     Margin="0,0,0,16"
                     Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button x:Name="AddDiagnosticHistoryButton"
                     AutomationProperties.Name="HistorySummary.AddDiagnosticHistoryButton"
                     Style="{StaticResource StandardActionButtonPrimary}"
                     Width="Auto"
                     Margin="0,0,5,0"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                     Content="Add Diagnostic"
                     Command="{Binding ElementName=DiagnosticHistoryUserControl, Path=DiagnosticHistoryAddCommand}"
                     CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=DiagnosticHistoryUserControl, Path=DiagnosticHistoryAddCommandParameter}"/>
            <Button  x:Name="ViewAllOrdersButton"
                     AutomationProperties.Name="HistorySummary.ViewAllOrdersButton"
                     Style="{StaticResource StandardActionButtonSecondary}"
                     Width="Auto"
                     Margin="5,0"
                     HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                     Content="View All Orders"
                     Command="{Binding ElementName=DiagnosticHistoryUserControl, Path=DiagnosticHistoryViewAllOrdersCommand}"
                     CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=DiagnosticHistoryUserControl, Path=DiagnosticHistoryViewAllOrdersCommandParameter}"/>
        </StackPanel>

        <Grid Grid.Row="1"
              Height="Auto"
              Margin="0,8,0,16">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                <Border BorderThickness="1"
                        BorderBrush="#92AEC4"
                        Background="White"
                        CornerRadius="3"
                        Height="20">
                    <Border.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="2" Color="Black" ShadowDepth="2" Opacity="0.16"/>
                    </Border.Effect>
                </Border>
                <Border BorderThickness="1"
                        BorderBrush="#92AEC4"
                        CornerRadius="3"
                        Background="White"
                        Height="20">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition />
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <RadioButton GroupName="DiagnosticSummaryToggle"
                                     Name="DiagnosticDisplayAll"
                                     AutomationProperties.Name="HistorySummary.DiagnosticDisplayAllButton"
                                     IsChecked="True"
                                     Grid.Column="0"
                                     Padding="16,6"
                                     Style="{StaticResource ButtonSetText}"
                                     Content="Display All"
                                     Command="{Binding ElementName=DiagnosticHistoryUserControl, Path=DiagnosticHistoryDisplayAllCommand}"
                                     CommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=DiagnosticHistoryUserControl, Path=DiagnosticHistoryDisplayAllCommandParameter}"/>
                        <Line Grid.Column="1" 
                              StrokeThickness="2" 
                              Stroke="#92AEC4"
                              X1="0"
                              Y1="0"
                              X2="0"
                              Y2="20"/>
                        <RadioButton Style="{StaticResource ButtonSetText}"
                                     GroupName="DiagnosticSummaryToggle"
                                     Name="DiagnosticSpecialtyOnly"
                                     AutomationProperties.Name="HistorySummary.DiagnosticSpecialtyOnly"
                                     Grid.Column="2"
                                     Padding="16,6"
                                     IsChecked="{Binding ElementName=DiagnosticHistoryUserControl, Path=DiagnosticHistoryDermatologyOnly, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True}"
                                     Content="Dermatology Only" />
                    </Grid>
                </Border>
            </Grid>

            <TextBlock Grid.Column="2"
                       Margin="0,0,6,0"
                       Style="{StaticResource BodyCopy3}"
                       Text="Resulted/Completed Orders"/>
        </Grid>

        <StackPanel Grid.Row="2">
            <DataGrid Name="DiagnosticHistoryGrid"
                      AutomationProperties.Name="HistorySummary.DiagnosticHistoryGrid"
                      Grid.Row="2"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=DiagnosticHistoryUserControl, Path=DiagnosticHistoryItemSource}"
                      SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=DiagnosticHistoryUserControl, Path=DiagnosticHistorySelectedItem}"
                      SelectionChanged="DiagnosticHistory_SelectionChanged"
                      Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=StackPanel}, Path=ActualWidth}"
                      ColumnWidth="*">
                <DataGrid.Columns>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Acttextdisplay}" 
                                        Header="Order"
                                        SortDirection="Ascending">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                            <Style>
                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Completeddate, Converter={StaticResource DateFormatConverter}}" 
                                        Header="Completed" 
                                        Width="Auto"/>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Interpretation">
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <TextBlock>
                                <TextBlock Name="InterpretationText" 
                                           Text="{Binding Path=Obsinterpretation, Converter={StaticResource KbmCapitalizeFirstLetterConverter}}" 
                                           TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                                <ui:WarningSmall x:Name="WarningImage" 
                                                 Visibility="Collapsed"/>
                            </TextBlock>
                                <DataTemplate.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Path=Obsinterpretation}" Value="abnormal">
                                        <Setter TargetName="InterpretationText" Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                                        <Setter TargetName="WarningImage" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                                    </DataTrigger>
                                </DataTemplate.Triggers>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
                    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Result"                                    
                                        Binding="{Binding Path=Obsvalue}">
                        <DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                            <Style>
                                <Setter Property="TextBlock.TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
                            </Style>
                        </DataGridTextColumn.ElementStyle>
                    </DataGridTextColumn>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{x:Null}"
                                            Width="102"
                                            CellTemplate="{StaticResource HoverAddHpiColumnTemplate}"
                                            CellStyle="{StaticResource HoverColumnStyle}"/>
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn Header="{x:Null}"
                                            Width="40"
                                            CellTemplate="{StaticResource HoverDeleteColumnTemplate}"
                                            CellStyle="{StaticResource HoverColumnStyle}"/>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
            </DataGrid>
            <StackPanel.Style>
                <Style TargetType="StackPanel">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=DiagnosticHistoryGrid, Path=Items.Count}" Value="0">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=DiagnosticHistoryGrid, Path=Items.Count}" Value="1"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Mng_Diag_Study_Ord_History_.IsDeleted}" Value="True"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </StackPanel.Style>
        </StackPanel>

        <Popup Style="{StaticResource GrowlDeletePopup}"
               PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=DiagnosticHistoryUserControl}">
            <ui:Growl x:Name="GrowlUserControl" 
                      Style="{StaticResource GrowlDeleteHistories}"
                      UndoCommand="{Binding ElementName=DiagnosticHistoryUserControl, Path=UndoCommand, Mode=TwoWay}"
                      UndoCommandParameter="{Binding ElementName=DiagnosticHistoryUserControl, Path=UndoCommandParameter, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </Popup>

        <TextBlock AutomationProperties.Name="HistorySummary.NoDiagnosticHistoryRecordsFound"
                   Height="18"
                   Grid.Row="2"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                   Text="No Diagnostic History records found.">
            <TextBlock.Style>
                <Style BasedOn="{StaticResource BodyCopy3}" TargetType="TextBlock">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=DiagnosticHistoryGrid, Path=Items.Count}" Value="0">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        </DataTrigger>
                        <MultiDataTrigger>
                            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding ElementName=DiagnosticHistoryGrid, Path=Items.Count}" Value="1"/>
                                <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Mng_Diag_Study_Ord_History_.IsDeleted}" Value="True"/>
                            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        </MultiDataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </TextBlock.Style>
        </TextBlock>

        <Rectangle Style="{StaticResource SeparatorLine}"
                   Grid.Row="3"
                   Margin="0,16"/>

        <history:HistoryReview Grid.Row="4"
                               DocumentDetail="{Binding Histories_.Docgen, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                               UnobtainedReason="{Binding Histories_.Hx_Unobtain_Reason, Mode=TwoWay, NotifyOnSourceUpdated=True, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                               Title="History Review for Diagnostic History"/>

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid},Path=DataContext.IsEncounterLocked}" Value="True">
<Setter Property="Button.IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

The binding should be Just relative source no need to set ancestor